# Something is going wrong in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk-tools

I have a problem with Android Studio

[image]

I can't find an Android SDK as selected component.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Nothing is Wrong** if it is already selected. I mean the

> **Selection is locked**

as because you can not choose whether to install Android Studio or not when the setup to install Android Studio is already made run by you after clicking on Android Studio Bundle.
And,

> **The second option shown to you as mentioned in your image is used to
>   choose whether you want to install the Android Virtual Devices.**

So, In order to install it completely with Android Virtual Devices click on Android Virtual Device.

Click on "Next" to complete installation after you have made your choice whether to install Android Studio along with Android Virtual Devices or not.

For Android SDK:

> You will have to **download it separately** as now it doesn't come with
>   the android studio bundle.

You can use this [link](http://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9FT-4TSz8ukYnJWQ3hJUmYyQzA/view) to download android SDK.

Comment: But a mean there must have be an <Android SDK> component.

Comment: Maybe it isn't installed

Comment: for android SDK you will have to install it separately. Now the bundle doesn't comes with android SDk.

Comment: Do you need help with installing SDK? I answered what you asked in the question.

Comment: I'm sorry, where can I find this bundle?

Comment: Bundle is android studio you just installed.

Comment: How can I fix it?

Comment: Now you want to install android sdk after installing Android studio bundle?

Comment: you can use this link https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9FT-4TSz8ukYnJWQ3hJUmYyQzA/view to download android sdk and dont forget to install the android platform tools based on your operating system.

Comment: Accept the answer by clicking on "tick" option near my answer as my answer attempts to provide answer to the question. In case if any other user with the same question comes searching for the answer can find the right answer.

Comment: I hope platform tools are clear to you and I hope I was able to fully help you out in your problem. :)